# How do you clear a session by using the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I've seen other ways to clear the session, but I'm interested in doing it from the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

database sessions

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

File based sessions

```
rake tmp:sessions:clear
```

Comment: I ran `rake tmp:sessions:clear` and it cleared my sessions, thanks! Does it prevent me from creating new ones by any chance?